# Python: write decimal number into binary file

Tags: python, binary, numbers, hex, decimal

I  need to replace a few bytes in ASN1 encoded binary file. Because of I'm completely out of ASN1 scope, I want to just replace some bytes starting at position 9 (offset) and of length 9 bytes.

I was able to open a file for binary write

```
fh = open("EmvData_3839_test.der", "r+b")
fh.seek(8)
fh.write(bytearray(9)) 
fh.close()
```

this replace my 9 bytes with 00 00 00 ....

I need to convert number e.g. 123456789012345678 to something like 
\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x00\x01... so that I can put it to fh.write() method and it will replace my old values with new. it is like a split a long number to single digits, then convert them to format \xYY and make an bytearray ? ( I mean to format what file.write() can handle)

Please consider that in python I cannot write even a basic loop without googling :)

thanks very much

Comment: Use `bytes(int(i)for i in str(your_num))`

Comment: Hi, thanks, however it returned something strange, like I'm missing some package to import?  >>> bytes(int(i)for i in str(123456789012345678))
'<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002202F30>'

Comment: No that should return a bytes object without any additional dependancies

Comment: I have c:\Python27>python --version
Python 2.7.9

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the error means - try `"".join(chr(int(i))for i in str(x))` instead

Comment: cool thanks, this looks much better :) >>> "".join(chr(int(i))for i in str(123456789012345678))
'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'

Comment: I just noticed some \t ??? instead of x09 but I can fix it by simply not using number 9 :)

Comment: `\t` IS `\x09`, they are the same character, don't worry its working as intended